# Can not read turkish characters from text file to string array

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding, text-files

I am trying to do some kind of sentence processing in turkish, and I am using text file for database. But I can not read turkish characters from text file, because of that I can not process the data correctly.

```
string[] Tempdatabase = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\dialogs.txt");
textBox1.Text = Tempdatabase[5];
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fiddle around using `Encoding` as much as you like. This might eventually yield the expected result, but bear in mind that this may not work with other files.

Usually, C# processes strings and files using Unicode by default. So unless you really need something else, you should try this instead:

Open your text file in notepad (or any other program) and save it as an **UTF-8** file. Then, you should get the expected results without any modifications in your code. This is because C# reads the file using the encoding you saved it with. This is default behavior, which should be preferred.

When you save your text file as UTF-8, then C# will interpret it as such.

This also applies to `.html` files inside Visual Studio, if you notice that they are displayed incorrectly (parsed with ASCII)

[image: saveas]

Comment: "C# processes strings and files using Unicode by default": not quite correct. Strings are Unicode/UTF-16 (`Encoding.Unicode`)—defaults don't enter into it. Files and streams usually default to Unicode/UTF-8 (`Encoding.UTF8`); it depends on the library, not the language.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably an encoding issue. Try using one of the Turkish [code page identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
var Tempdatabase =
    File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\dialogs.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
```

Answer (score 3):

The file contains the text in a specific Turkish character set, not Unicode. If you don't specify any other behaviour, .net will assume Unicode text when reading text from a text file. You have two possible solutions:

Either change the text file to use Unicode (for example utf8) using an external text editor.

Or specify a specific character set to read for example:

```
string[] Tempdatabase = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\dialogs.txt", Encoding.Default);
```

This will use the local character set of the Windows system.

```
string[] Tempdatabase = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\dialogs.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1254");
```

This will use the Turkish character set defined by Microsoft.