# Character problem while getting information from vCard in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

Here is my vCard content:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Büyükçarşıbaşıoğlu;Oğuz;;;
FN:BüyükçarşıbaşıoğluOğuz
ORG:;
TEL;CELL;VOICE:019365478236598742588952
END:VCARD
```

When I try to parse it like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.vcf");
var get = lines.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("N:"));  
var splt = get?.Replace("N:", "").Split(';').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

var first_name = splt != null && splt.Length > 1 ? string.Join(" ", splt.Skip(1).Take(5).ToArray()) : splt?[0];
var last_name = splt != null && splt.Length > 1 ? splt?[0] : string.Empty;

var result = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(last_name) ? first_name + " " + last_name : first_name;

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

It causes a problem with Turkish characters like this:

[image]

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: It is an Encoding problem. Try to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415132/can-not-read-turkish-characters-from-text-file-to-string-array

Comment: @ManedWolf - I didn't know `iso-8859-9`. I have tried `utf-8`. I was wondering if vCard is different. Problem is solved. Can you help me close the topic by writing in reply or in any other way that is appropriate for community boards?

Comment: You can add your own solution to this post, if you solved the problem specific for vCard.

Answer (score 3):

Please set encoding of file to utf-8.
You can create a new file and save as utf-8,
Otherwise you should get encoding of vCard file and tell the file reader.

For obtain encoding of the file you can use this method:

```
private static Encoding GetEncoding(string file)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default, true))
    {
        if (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            reader.Read();

        return reader.CurrentEncoding;
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
        var encoding = GetEncoding("yourfile");
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("yourfile", encoding);
```

Comment: How? Like this: `var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.vcf", Encoding.UTF8);` It causes the same problem.